# I'm trying to make my model have a texture that flashes different colors at once

Tags: texturing, particles, import, color

I need to know how to make the yellow fur texture become as a flashing color texture.

The colors for the flashing texture are in this order:
**red - blue - green - yellow - white - purple**

They have to be pastel variants of these colors in order to make this Super Sonic model become Hyper Sonic.

The particles should be sparkles.
[image: Here's the model that I imported!]

Answer (score 1):

This is just one of many methods. My example features 3 colors, but you can add as many as you need. 
Here's the node setup (it is recommended you put everything in a node group, like I did. If you don't make sure there's a value input node in the place of the group input):
[image]
First, it takes the value and compares it to a set number. Then, it changes the color depending on which value is true (You don't need one for the first color, since that's the color that will be displayed when all other values return false)
I've animated the value with a simple linear function generator, and below is the resulting animation:
[image]